# Bounded Variation is Bounded

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ and let $D=\{x_o,x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a division of $[a,b]$.
>   We say that $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ if 
>   $\displaystyle \sup_{D\in \mathscr{D}} \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|<\infty$, where $\mathscr{D}$ is a collection of divisions of $[a,b]$.

My question is: Does Bounded Variation implies that a function is Bounded?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Look $BV(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ in fact 
$$|f(x)| = |f(x)-f(a)+f(a)|\le|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|\le|f(a)|+M$$

Where M is the total variation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because for arbitrary $x$ you can easily find $D$ showing that $|f(x)-f(a)|\le $ the given bound.

Comment: You mean $D=\{a,x\}$?

Comment: How can I arrive at boundedness using the definition of a bounded variation?Thanks.

Comment: @PhilipBenjMarcobyEragon Yes - or $\{a,x,b\}$ if your definition might additionally require $x_0=a$, $x_n=b$.

Answer (score 0):

For any division $D \in \mathfrak{D}$, the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| \leq \sup_{D\in\mathfrak{D}} \sum_{i=1}^n|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| =: C < \infty$ holds. For any $x \in [a,b]$, let $D = \{a,x\}$ so you get $|f(x)-f(a)| \leq C \Rightarrow |f(x)| = |f(x)-f(a)+f(a)| \leq |f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)| \leq C+|f(a)|$.